# How to display error message to User when InvocableMethod throws an exception

Tags: apex, process-builder, error-messages, invocable-method

**Background**

I am using Process Builder to run an Apex `InvocableMethod` which sends some data to a 3rd party REST API.

Sometimes the 3rd party REST API returns a validation error.

**Question**

How can I return this message from the `InvocableMethod` to the User as a friendly popup message?

Similar to how triggers allow this:

```
.addError('REST API Validation Message Goes Here!');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot perform a callout after a transaction has started a DML operation, so your callout would necessarily need to be asynchronous, starting some time after the record is committed to the database. As such, there's no way to return an error to the user, and subsequently cancel the save operation, because it runs in a separate transaction. The best you could hope for is to do something like sending a message or updating/deleting a record.

Comment: Is there anyway to return a friendly error message from an `InvocableMethod`?

Comment: This is no longer true is it?  The flow will commit the DML and start a new transaction, per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_flow_invocable_action_callout.htm